# Wix Bootstrapper automated versioning with Setup MSI

Tags: c#, wix

I am trying to incorporate automated version via AssemblyInfo `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2.0.*")]`.  I have added the `Version="!(bind.FileVersion.FILEEXE)"` to the Product.wxs in my setup which generates an MSI file.  According to my reading, MSI does not have a version property for me to access in the Bundle.wxs in the Bootstrapper project.  How can I set the version in Bootstrapper to sync with my application's version automatically?

Answer (score 0):

In your bootstrapper's `<Bundle>` element use attribute `Version="!(bind.packageVersion.YourPackageName)"`

Where `YourPackageName`is the Id of the `MsiPackage` in the chain you wish to use the attribute from.

You can also bind all the other attributes this way, bundle name, manufacturer, etc.

Reference (near the bottom, package properties) http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/light.html

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried this already.  in my Product.wxs I have `Version="!(bind.FileVersion.EXE)"` where EXE is the ID of the File.  and in my Bundle I have `Version="!(bind.packageVersion.Setup)"` where Setup is the ID of the MSI that was compiled by the Product project.